# MySQL Развернуть строки в столбцы

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такой запрос в базу:

```html
select post_id, meta_key, meta_value from kane_postmeta 
WHERE `post_id` = '22680' 
and meta_key IN ('_sku', '_product_attributes')
```

Выдает вот такой результат:

```html
post_id | meta_key | meta_value
_______________________________
22680   | _sku     | CK11111
_______________________________
22680   | _product_attributes | значение
```

Надо получить в таком виде:

```html
post_id | _sku    | _product_attributes
_______________________________
22680   | CK11111 | значение
```

Comment: если  в каждом случае вы ожидаете по одной строке, то проще всего два подзапроса сделать. Либо группировка с case

Comment: Это PIVOT. Обычно используется условное агрегирование. Для неопределённого списка полей - динамическим SQL.